# Is it possible that $A\cdot B= I$, but that $B\cdot A\neq I$?

Tags: matrices, inverse

I know that $A\cdot A^{-1}=A^{-1}\cdot A = I$, but is it possible for a matrix $B$ to exist such that $A\cdot B= I$, but  $B\cdot A\neq I$? If that it is not the case, why not?

($I$ is the identity matrix)

Comment: $A\cdot B=I\implies A^{-1}A\cdot B = A^{-1}I\implies B = A^{-1}$.

Comment: Perhaps you mean to ask if $A, B$ are $n\times n$ matrices, and $I$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix.  Then $A\cdot B =I \iff B\cdot A= I$.  Else all bets are off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you don’t require the matrices to be square; J. W. Tanner’s answer provides an example. If you do require $B$ to be square, however, it is true that if $AB=I$, then $BA=I$; there is a short proof [here](https://people.math.carleton.ca/~kcheung/math/notes/MATH1107/wk06/06_left_inverse_is_right_inverse.html), for instance.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible if $A$ and $B$ are not square matrices;

for example, $\pmatrix{1&0}\pmatrix{1\\0}=\pmatrix{1}$, but $\pmatrix{1\\0}\pmatrix{1&0}=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}$